# How to append regression coefficients from multiple models?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logistic-regression

I have multiple Y variables and I am running a loop to create multiple models. I have to create a 2-d numpy array with all the coefficients. Facing an error with in the same.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)    
accuracy_logistic = np.ones(100,dtype = float)
model_log = []
y_pred_output = np.array([])
    pred_coef = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0,100):  

        model_log = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
        model_log.fit(X_train,y_train[:,i])
        log_prediction = model_log.predict(X_test)
        accuracy_logistic[i] = accuracy_score(y_test[:,i],log_prediction)

       ##Error inline below##

        pred_coef = np.append(pred_coef, np.transpose(np.array(model_log.coef_)), axis= 0)
```

Error Message

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
---> 12     pred_coef = np.append(pred_coef, np.transpose(np.array(model_log.coef_)), axis= 0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   4526         values = ravel(values)
   4527         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4528     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your goal, but I think your mistake is in the following line:

```
pred_coef = np.append(pred_coef, np.transpose(np.array(model_log.coef_)), axis= 0)
```

You've created a DataFrame pred_coef so it seems you should be using the df.append functionality.

```
pred_coef = pred_coef.append(pd.Series(model_log.coef_[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

This should provide you with a DataFrame with each row being the coefficients for the given y.

EDIT: @Alollz makes a good point that iteratively appending to a DataFrame is inefficient. This can be done simply by creating a list before your loop rather than creating the pred_coef DataFrame and appending the coefficients to it. Then you can construct your Dataframe from the list. For example,

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)    
accuracy_logistic = np.ones(y.shape[1],dtype = float)
model_log = []
y_pred_output = np.array([])
coef_list = []

for i in range(0,y.shape[1]):  
    model_log = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
    model_log.fit(X_train,y_train[:,i])
    log_prediction = model_log.predict(X_test)
    accuracy_logistic[i] = accuracy_score(y_test[:,i],log_prediction)
    coef_list.append(model_log.coef_[0])

pred_coef = pd.DataFrame(coef_list)
```

Comment: Though you shouldn't append to a `DataFrame` within a loop, as it needlessly copies data every iteration and is horribly inefficient. Better to append to a list and call the `DataFrame` constructor once at the end.

Comment: @ALollz I've read this is referred to as "quadratic copying" and makes iterative appending O(n^2) so tend to avoid it. I believe this is because DataFrames are essentially stacked Series, and Series are not size-mutable but only value-mutable (although I shouldn't be quoted on that). I'll edit my answer.